# Why the return value of functions being printed in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Very new to python, trying this -

```
def newlines():
    print()
    print()
    print()    
question = "Which online Course you have signed up, dude?"
response = "Good Luck to you, dude!"
print(question), newlines(), input(), newlines(), print(response)
```

In Python 3.2.* the output is this

```
Which online Course you have signed up, dude?



Nothing



Good Luck to you, dude!

(None, None, "Nothing", None) # Where this output is coming from ?
```

Also this is not happening with python 3.3 beta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must be at the interactive shell. When I run your code as a file, I get this output:

```
$ python3.2 test.py
Which online Course you have signed up, dude?



dlkjdf



Good Luck to you, dude!
$
```

You only get your output at the console:

```
>>> def newlines():
...     print()
...     print()
...     print()    
... 
>>> question = "Which online Course you have signed up, dude?"
>>> response = "Good Luck to you, dude!"
>>> 
>>> print(question), newlines(), input(), newlines(), print(response)
Which online Course you have signed up, dude?



dljdldk



Good Luck to you, dude!
(None, None, 'dljdldk', None, None)
>>>
```

This is because the console will print the representation of the last thing you typed in. The last statement is actually a tuple, so it gets printed at the end. Here's some examples:

```
>>> 3
3
>>> 4
4
>>> 3, 4, None, "hey"
(3, 4, None, 'hey')
```

Answer (score 2):

When you write this:

`print(question), newlines(), input(), newlines(), print(response)`

It is actually a tuple, which holds the result of each function.

Simply breaking up the calls on individual lines will solve your problem.

```
print(question)
newlines()
input()
newlines()
print(response)
```

Comment: +1 you should write it like this regardless of the information in the other answer. `,` is not a statement separator in Python. If you want to do several things in sequence, then do several things in sequence.